# How to send POST request through RestTemplate with custom parameter in header

Tags: java, javascript, spring, http, resttemplate

I need to send post request with custom parameter("data" containing path) and set content type as text/plain. I looked through a ton of similar question but none of the solutions posted helped.

The method should list files from this directory.

my code is

```
    public List<FileWrapper> getFileList() {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("data", "/public/");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(
            map, headers);
    String url = "http://192.168.1.51:8080/pi/FilesServlet";
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    String response = restTemplate
            .postForObject(url, request, String.class);
    List<FileWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String part : response.split("\\|")) {
        System.out.println("part " + part);
        list.add(new FileWrapper(part));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here's working code equivalent written in javascript:

```
function getFileList(direction){
$("div.file-list").html("<center><progress></progress></center>");
$.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.1.51:8080/pi/FilesServlet",
  type: "POST",
  data: direction ,
  contentType: "text/plain"
})
```

The parameter is not added as the request returns empty string meaning the path is not valid. The expected response is `file_name*file_size|file_name*file_size ...`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UrlEncode the $data field value and append it at its place in the url String

Comment: @RobertRowntree `data` is not a part of the url, this is `POST` method, `data` value is an argument.

Comment: then write it to the output stream on the Connection  or put it into the 'Entity' depending on what client is being used.

Comment: @RobertRowntree The thing is I want to avoid using `HttpUrlConnection` and use Spring's `RestTemplate` instead to handle connections

Comment: @Asalas77 is the input data in AJAX request in this format? `{'data':'/public/'}` Can you print direction in JS code and post that back here?

Comment: @nilesh I can't run the file now, but this method is called in corresponding html like that: `<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  getFileList("/public/");
 });
</script>`

Comment: What does `getFileList` return? That's what you should be passing as data to your POST request. Probably it's returning a set of file in a certain format that you would need to pass and not just the string `/public/`?

Comment: @nilesh `direction` is a folder directory. It's returning `String` formatted as `file_name*file_size|file_name*file_size ...` of files in that directory or an empty `String` if the path is not valid or the directory is empty (but I know it's not). Later in the js file there's `.success(function(received) {
 if(received!=""&&received!=null){
 var files =  received.split("|");` and some more code. I also have similar code in java, but I always get an empty `String` from the `restTemplate` response so I don't even get this far.

Comment: Are you able to execute this request via curl? `curl -i -k -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -X POST -d '{"data":"/public/"}' "http://192.168.1.51:8080/pi/FilesServlet"`

Comment: @nilesh the curl i was given to use is slightly different `curl  -X POST --data "/private/" --header "Content-Type: text/plain" localhost:2222/pi/FilesServlet` but I'm not at work at the moment and I can't do it remotely, so I will try both tomorrow morning and check back here with the results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it's quite clear that your request object isn't correct. If you are passing a plain string containing folder name, then you don't need a `MultiValueMap`. Just try sending a string,

```
    String data = "/public/"
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(
            data, headers);
    String url = "http://192.168.1.51:8080/pi/FilesServlet";
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    String response = restTemplate
            .postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

Comment: Could you show an example how to send a file with this method as multipart form data?

Comment: Did you try content type header to `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`